# Use dynamic text in report header or footer based on the subreport running on that page

Tags: reporting-services

Here are the steps I've taken:

1. I have created one subreport with a report Footer.
2. Then I call this subreport in the main report.
3. When I run the main report the sub report footer part does not show in the main report.

I've searched I found that this is the limitation of SSRS.

I changed things so the main report has a footer with some expressions.

To elaborate, I have three reports:

- MainReport
- SubReport1
- SubReport2

I am calling Subreport1 and Subreport2 in the MainReport. I have added a page break between Subreport1 and Subreport2 in the MainReport.

Now in my main report footer part I have one Textbox and there I want to show some text as per the subreport details showing in the respective pages.

For example, suppose when I run the main report my subreport1 gives me 3 pages of report and Subreport2 gives me 5 pages of report. Now from PageNo-1 to 3 I want to show "*This is my Subreport1 Part*" and from pageNo-4 to 8 want to show "*This is my Subreport2 part*".

Is there any way to sort out this issue?

Comment: AFAIK this can't be done. Someone may prove me wrong though.

Comment: You could cheat by adding a hidden text field to both reports and just pull the "This is my Subreport1 Part" from that field on each report?

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap the two sub reports in a Table.

First I would create a Dataset which returns two rows eg

SELECT 'Subreport1' as Report
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Subreport2'

Then I would add a Table and set that Dataset as the source. I would delete most of the columns and rows leaving just one column and the detail row.

I would resize that cell wide enough for the widest sub report, and high enough to fit both sub reports. Then I would move both subreports inside that cell.

I would set the Hidden property on each subreport so it only shows on the row matching it's name eg

= Fields!Report.Value = "Subreport1"

Now (finally) you can reference that Textbox in your footer, using the ReportItems syntax.